# How to add new column using CAST and info from another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, calculated-columns, alter-table

I'm trying to understand the relationship between two operations in SQL - ADD COLUMN and CAST().
I tried to create a new column containing the lengths of another column's values, while that other column is inconveniently of type INTEGER:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory 
    ADD inventory_id_len AS (CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(inventory_id AS VARCHAR)) FROM rental);
```

But it returns:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 4:  ADD inventory_id_len AS (CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(inventory_id AS V...
```

Thanks.

Comment: A subquery is not allowed for a generated column.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would help.

Comment: Yes definitely. Even though there are already some answers, I will add what the desired results are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you need to [use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6.2.18.1.2) the `generated always ... stored` syntax to add a computed column. For your use case, that would look like:

```
alter table inventory 
    add inventory_id_len int 
    generated always as (char_length(inventory_id::text)) stored
;
```

A subquery makes no sense in that context; the computed column takes the value of column `inventory_id` on the very same row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the length of the id as a generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory 
    ADD inventory_id_len INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LEN(inventory_id::text) STORED;
```

Because Postgres does not (yet) support virtual generated columns, a view might be more in line with what you want:

```
create view v_inventory as
    select i.*, len(inventory_id::text) as inventory_id_len
    from inventory i;
```